# drag and drop image game in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a drag and drop game. The user must choose the correct shape for drag and drop to combine box. when users have the wrong object, it will move to mulai.java if true then it will move to levelbuka.java. I have tried this:

```
private ImageView myImage,Image2;

private Button submit;
private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG = "The Android Logo";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.leveldasar1);


    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    // Sets the tag
    myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    myImage.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);
    myImage.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());

    Image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
    Image2.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);
    Image2.setOnLongClickListener(new MyClickListener());
    // set the listener to the dragging data



    //myImage.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());        
    findViewById(R.id.toplinear).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (R.id.bottomlinear == R.drawable.kalkulator){
                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),levelbuka.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }else {
                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mulai.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
```

but when I hit the submit button, then the statement will be executed no one is moved to mulai.java although the picture is correct incorporation. What am I missing in here?

Comment: I answered it, plz see if it works.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. where have you answered man?

Comment: Your code does not do anything that can pass the images to mulai.class  or levelbuka.class.

Comment: when i touch button submit, it always move to mulai.class